Why is Boost.log record_ostream.hpp failing (m_record != null) assertion in get_record()?
This is thrown when I try to run the binary. CMake and ninja builds just fine.
Exact error message:
Assertion failed: (m_record != __null), function get_record, file /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp, line 161.

Line causing the error:
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Started TCP server";

Current environment:

Architecture: ARM (MacBookPro M3)
OS: MacOS
Compiler used: g++-11 (from Homebrew)
Boost version: 1.74

It is working fine on linux environment:

Architecture: Both ARM (running UTM on MacOS to virtualize) and x86-64 (running on AWS EC2 instance)
OS: Debian 12
Compiler used: g++-11
Boost version: 1.74

Using this combination of g++ and boost versions as there is some bug on Debian 12 where you can't compile Boost 1.74 with g++-12.
Update:
When I write a simple program,
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main()
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "hello";
}

it throws
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast


You need to make this a self-contained example. Right now this is unanswerable. My best bet is that there's a ODR violation (building against different version/flags than found at runtime?)

Hmm, wouldn't ODR be caught during compile time? Version-wise, everything should be the same as they all use the same CMake file. Added a new example in the post, not sure if it helps.

ODR cannot always be diagnosed. Even if it can it's not "Diagnostic Required"
